# typeahead doesn't list matching strings with remote option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using twitter's [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). When I use remote to get json, it shows first 5 strings of json irrespective of character I type in the text box.

Here is the configuration

```
$("#search").typeahead({
    name: 'categories',
    cache: false,
    remote: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/charts/sales/categories?chart_token=atoken',
    valueKey: 'name'
});
```

The above url returns following json

```
[{"id":"22","name":"PC"},{"id":"185","name":"XBOX 360"},{"id":"31","name":"Keräilykortti"},{"id":"34","name":"Manga + Kirjat"},{"id":"3","name":"DVD-elokuvat"},{"id":"202","name":"Wii"},{"id":"552","name":"Wii U"},{"id":"431","name":"Laitteet"},{"id":"535","name":"Nintendo 3DS"},{"id":"167","name":"Nintendo DS"},{"id":"206","name":"PlayStation 3"},{"id":"172","name":"PSP"},{"id":"26","name":"PlayStation 2"},{"id":"532","name":"PS Vita"},{"id":"25","name":"Xbox"},{"id":"241","name":"BLU-RAY-elokuvat"},{"id":"178","name":"Erikoistuotteet"},{"id":"30","name":"Games Workshop"},{"id":"328","name":"Flames of War"},{"id":"513","name":"Muut miniatyyripelit"},{"id":"32","name":"Roolipelit"},{"id":"33","name":"Lautapelit"}]
```

If I use `local` with above json instead of `remote` it works perfectly.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: What content-type is returned by your server for typeahead request? It should be 'application/json'.

Comment: I verified. It is json only.

Comment: Do you see the network call to the url? And as it is open source, you can debug it yourself (with the unminified version) and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed issue by specifying `prefetch` instead of `remote`. So below configuration works

```
$("#search").typeahead({
    name: 'categories',
    cache: false,
    prefetch: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/charts/sales/categories?chart_token=atoken',
    valueKey: 'name'
});
```

`prefetch` - Prefetches data and stores it in localStorage

`remote` - When prefetched data is insufficient, typeahead uses this source to get more data for suggestions